# Prove if $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} (c_k)^{1/k}=0$, the the radius of convergence $R=\infty$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

Prove if $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} (c_k)^{1/k}=0$, the the radius of convergence of the power series, $\sum_{k \geq 0}c_k(z-z_0)^k$, $R=\infty$.

It's already proved in our textbook that $$R=\frac{1}{\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} (c_k)^{1/k}}$$
Can we say simply that if $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} (c_k)^{1/k}=0$, then $R=\infty$? Do we need a more detailed proof here? And if so, how to prove it? Thanks.

Comment: How did they prove that theorem? Just adopt the proof. It's just the root test.

Comment: @ZacharySelk It is proved in our textbook, but with the assumption $R < \infty$.

Comment: That's why I said "adopt" and not "copy".

Comment: Though "adapting" it might be preferable, if you don't want to deal with the legal hassles, or are not ready to raise a little proof all on your own.